# Unknown Server tag ASP.NET 2.0 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am in the process of upgrading a website from Visual Studio 2005 to 2010.  I ran it through the importer, however I'm having some errors.  Specifically I'm having the following error:

```
Error   615 Unknown server tag 'CTL:PayPal'
```

If I go to the file that it is complaining about I have the following at the top of the file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="PowerShop.Admin.UI.Customer.Controls.CustomerPaymentList" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CTL" TagName="OrderPaymentList" Src="~/Order/Controls/OrderPaymentList.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CTL" TagName="PayPal" Src="~/Order/Controls/OrderWizard/PayPalDetail.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CTL" TagName="Term" Src="~/Order/Controls/OrderWizard/LineOfCreditDetail.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Shipping" TagName="AddressVerification" Src="~/Controls/AddressVerificaton.ascx" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="PowerShop.Configuration" %>
```

I have checked and double checked the register tags and the file but everythin appears to be correct.  The file exists (PayPalDetail.ascx) in the exact location I am specifying.  This page does not throw any errors on any of the other register tags. Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you add the header of PayPalDetail.ascx too?

Comment: <%@ Control Language="c#" Inherits="PowerShop.Admin.UI.Order.Controls.OrderWizard.PayPalDetail" %>

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be in wrong place like you could have by mistake put it in the page instead of putting it in the `UserControl` which have the `Register` tag.

Also, this can occur if the `Paypal user control` is not able to compile due to some bug in it.

> > Where are you placing the `CTL:Paypal` tag ??

.

> PS: More detailed question could have a chance of more detailed answer !